# How to check if a value(substring) exists in every JSON object in an array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How to verify if string 'test' exists in every object in the below array.

```js
var el = [{
  "id": 28,
  "Title": "US",
  "Name":"testA"
}, {
  "id": 56,
  "Title": "US",
  "Name":"testB" 
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "Title": "testDefault",
  "Name":"Joe" 
}]
```

I can do `el.find(a =>a.Title.includes("test"))` when I know the key. How do I check it if key is not known?

Comment: this is not clear: your question concerns an existence in el, and your example uses a find that returns the first line concerned, these are 2 different things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that requires `every` object in the array to have at least `some` (i.e., at least one) of it's `values` to be a string and include the string `"test"`.

```js
var el = [
  { id: 28, Title: "US", Name: "testA" },
  { id: 56, Title: "US", Name: "testB" },
  { id: 89, Title: "testDefault", Name: "Joe" },
];

const exists = el.every(obj => {
  return Object.values(obj).some(item => {
    return typeof item === "string" && item.includes("test");
  });
});

console.log(exists);
```